# pylab cannot find reference for its modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, python-module

I have a mac OS X Yosimite and I'm using python 2.7.10 and Pycharm as my IDLE. I have pylab installed properly but I cannot use any of its modules.

When a try:

```
from pylab import show
```

(or any module) it says

```
ImportError: cannot import name show
```

But when I run just the line `import pylab` I get no errors!

I tried leaving that way and calling the module anyway.

```
pylab.imshow(...)
```

But I got the same error obviously. Do I have to install those modules separately?
PS: I'm almost sure the problem has nothing to do with the interpreter

Answer (score 2):

Try importing from `matplotlib.pyplot`, rather than from `pylab` ([this is now the recommended way to import `matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#matplotlib-pyplot-and-pylab-how-are-they-related)):

From example:

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import imshow
imshow()
```

Or:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow()
```